# Modal only pops up once after a refresh maybe 1 out 10 times. Why does it do this?

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I have a site view modal and it pops up maybe once every ten times after a refresh. Why does it do this? Could it be interference of different JS on my page? I have checked other posts about this issue and none of their solutions have worked for me.

```
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Launch    
        modal</a>
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Write Your Review</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
      [site_reviews_form assign_to="post_id"]
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console at the times where it does not show up?

Comment: no specific error in the console related to the modal